Why 'routerLink' is not working on Angular 17?
I am creating a personal project using Angular 17. For the navigation I am using routerLink to create dynamic views. The problem that I have found is in a products page.
I have a products list page and a product's detail page. For acceding to the list page I have to got to the route /app/products/, and for acceding to the product's detail page I have to go to /app/products/id
I have this configuration in the routing module of the products
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/products-list/products-list.component')
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/product-detail/product-detail.component')
  }
];

In the product's list HTML I have this line that should redirect to the product's detail page
<a [routerLink]="['/', product.id]" style="display: inline-block;" class="mx-1">
When I click on the anchor, Angular shows me the next error in the browser's console

core.mjs:7473 ERROR Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '9818011'

Both components are standalone, and in products list component I have imported the RouterLinkWithHref
The main app.routes.ts is this one
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'app',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/layout/layout.module').then((m) => m.LayoutModule)
    }
];

Then is the layoutRouting that looks like this
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './components/layout/layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m)=>m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'products',
        loadChildren: () => import('../products/products.module').then((m)=>m.ProductsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'clients',
        loadChildren: () => import('../clients/clients.module').then((m)=>m.ClientsModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }

and finally is the products routing that looks like this
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from '../layout/components/layout/layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/products-list/products-list.component')
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    loadComponent: () => import('./pages/product-detail/product-detail.component')
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule { }


Can you provide how you register the routes? Is this routes root/top-level route?

@YongShun I have updated the post with all the routing modules and the main app.routes.ts

Your routeLink for ProductDetail component should be: [routerLink]="['/app/products/', product.id]"

Ohh now I understand why when I tried that way didn't work. I was not adding the '/' at the start of app. Thank you very much!

You should use nested routing with the children keyword.
The first path should be the original address and the second path should be the id.
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/products-list/products-list.component'),
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/product-detail/product-detail.component')
      }
    ]
  },
];

<a [routerLink]="['/products', product.id]" style="display: inline-block;" class="mx-1">


I tried this way and didn't work, still shows the same error. But if I keep the path as in the coment from Yong Shun, it works.
